# how get "last url" for each row after joining a table full of urls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table like in the photo linked below, I used this query to join these tables:

```
declare @ID INT = 1

select *
from PhotoAlbum_Table,Photo_Table
where PhotoAlbum_Table.ID=@ID 
  and ( PhotoAlbum_Table.PhotoAlbumID=Photo_Table.PhotoAlbumID)
```

but I need to eliminate some records (those that have same primary key) after joining these tables but dont know how, I marked them on the photo.

I want all albums of a user, with the last photoUrl that they have uploaded to that album.

link to image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/54uosj.jpg

Comment: Those rows aren't duplicate...

Comment: @nhgrif yes , but primary keys are

Comment: But this isn't a table--it's a select joined to a table that you have a one-to-many relationship.  You can't join with a one-to-many and not duplicate primary keys from the one and have all the information.

Comment: Domino, what do you want to have in the results? Do you want to have unique ALBUMS or unique PHOTOS? You can't easily get unique-albums-and-unique-photos at the same time because (as in your example) sometimes an album have many photos. You'd need to throw away some photos and usually it's not actually what you want. Please describe exactly what you want to have afterwards. Write down for us some example of a good query result.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl , i want all album of a user , with the last photoUrl that they have uploaded to that album to set that url as album cover

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the proper ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) - please stop using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your selections together.

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1;
SELECT <Choose the specific items you want> FROM PhotoAlbum_Table AS a
INNER JOIN Photo_Table AS p ON a.PhotoAlbumID = p.PhotoAlbumID
WHERE a.ID = @ID;
GROUP BY <The specific items> --Add this line
```

**EDIT**

Based on the new information I would use.

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1;
WITH cte (
    PhotoAlbumID,
    PhotoID,
    PhotoAlbumDate,
    PhotoAlbumName,
    PrivacyID
) AS (
    SELECT a.PhotoAlbumID,
        MAX(p.PhotoID)
        a.PhotoAlbumDate, 
        a.PhotoAlbumName, 
        a.PrivacyID
    FROM PhotoAlbum_Table AS a
    INNER JOIN Photo_Table AS p ON a.PhotoAlbumID = p.PhotoAlbumID
    WHERE a.ID = @ID;
    GROUP BY a.PhotoAlbumID, 
        a.PhotoAlbumDate, 
        a.PhotoAlbumName, 
        a.PrivacyID
)
SELECT cte.*, u.PhotoUrl FROM cte
INNER JOIN Photo_Table AS u ON cte.PhotoID = u.PhotoID;
```

Comment: http://oi62.tinypic.com/ajug5e.jpg

Comment: thanks for the clarifications! btw. on ssql2008+ you can use rownumber-over to get the same effect much easier

Comment: @quetzalcoatl oh cool. I'll have to look that up. I originally didn't know exactly what the OP wanted, but once he explained I updated my answer.

Comment: syntax error ! i remove ; after WHERE a.ID = @ID and also it says 'cte' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: Geesh, Domino, please add some of your own work to it. You can correct typos and some misspelling, right? Please, don't set your mind on exact solution. Try understanding what the code above does and use the knowledge to write your own query tailored to your tables.

Comment: @SnareChops: I've added an answer that roughly shows how it'd look with partitioning. While the max(id) trick is really helpful sometimes, it's useless when somebody is using UUID as primary keys. (Of course here we have ints, so that's not the point). Partitioning functions allow you to run some function over a "segment" of a result set. The rownumber-ordered-by-date is ridiculously useful for things like "latest edit" or "five last comments". Just FYI :)

Comment: after some changes it works now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this type of queries are in general not easy, at least for the first time. That's because the SQL language is not helpful when defining things like "lastest URL", it's easy to fetch "latest Date", or "greatest ID" (assuming you have some autonumbering).

But for "lastest URL" you have to basically split the problem into "lastest URL modification Date" and then "the URL that matches the latest Date".

However, if you work on relatively recent sql server (2008+), you can write it down with the help of row numbering and partitioning functions. If you select all the things you are doing now, and rownumber() them over the URL Date, then you will be able to pick the rows where rownumber==1.

In short:

- write a select-join similar to what you have now
- add a rownumbering to it, `partitioned by albumId` and `ordered descending by photoDate`
- then, you will have to wrap all of that with another query
- which will filter the rows by something like `where rownumber = 1`

In very rough sketch it will look like:

```
select *
from
(
   select
     al.albumid,
     ...
     ph.photourl,
     rownumber() over (
          partition by al.albumid
          order by ph.photoDate
     ) as rn
   from albums al
   join photos ph on ph.album = al.albumid
) 
where tmp.rn = 1
```

but that's a sketch, adjust that to your needs

Comment: thanks for your edit and helps , i cant +1 your answer because of my low rep thanks anyway ;)